# How to build and run Android-Eye

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Lately, while attempting to build an interesting open source android-web streamer: [Android-Eye](https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye), I noticed that several people, including myself have been stumped by process of building the application given that it contains c/c++ code that (I think) needs to be compiled by the android ndk before anything can work.  The fact that the dev doesn't seem to be active anymore doesn't make this any easier.

I've been trying to get this to work for well over 3 days now and can say with full confidence that I do not posses the knowledge (especially for the ndk) to get this thing built.  The long list of things i've tried is too extensive to be covered in this post but here are a few git issues posted by others that have experienced similar issues as me:

https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/issues/32

https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/issues/27

I understand that it may look as if I am asking to be "spoonfed" the process of building the application but a few pushes in the right direction would be excellent :)

BTW, I have access to windows and mac boxes incase that influences the build process.

Thanks

Comment: Hey did u get any solutions ?